# data not updating in component after adding new object to an array reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-context

i'm using `context API` that's why i defined object(which is array inside it) outside of functionProvider, and inside function I'm adding new object to an array which is working. when I check in `console.log` new item is added but in component where I'm mapping is not updated

```
let data = {
    todos: [...],
}

export function TodoProvider({ children }) {    
    const addNewTask = (title, setTitle) => {
        let lastId = data.todos.length
        data.todos = [...data.todos, { title, completed: false, id: lastId + 1 }]
        setTitle("")
        // WHEN I CONSOLE.LOG HERE NEW OBJECT IS ADDED
    }

    return (
        <TodoContext.Provider value={{ data, addNewTask }}>
            {children}
        </TodoContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

> the component where I'm `mapping`

```
export default function TodoList() {
    const { data } = useContext(TodoContext)

    return (
        <ul>
            {data.todos.length ? (
                data.todos.map((item) => {
                    return <TodoItem {...item} />
                })
            ) : (
                <h2>Nothing in todolist yet</h2>
            )}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Comment: Only changes to state make component rerender

Comment: is there any way tho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set data as a state

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    todos: [...],
})

const addNewTask = (title, setTitle) => {
    let lastId = data.todos.length
    setData({ todos: [...data.todos, { title, completed: false, id: lastId + 1 }] })
    setTitle("")
}
```

Comment: This won't work.  Should be `setData({ todos: ... })`. I would just remove the wrapper object